# large sql table - select all but show progressively show with javascript / PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a large SQL table with user historical data something like this:

```
ID    Name     Units     Company      Benefit  Date
1     John     1.5       Example A    300$     1/1/2016
2     Paul     2.12      Example B    600$     1/2/2016
3     Mike     3.21      Example A    250$     1/3/2016 
...
```

I need to load all data to make some complex calcs: yield, total, by company...

And then I need to show all data in table but I want to to this progressively like infinite scroll, pagination or Ajax load. But I can't make SQL LIMIT because a need to load all data first.

The solution will be make 2 queries: one with all data, then one with LIMIT

The page I need finally is something like this:

```
**Hi John,**

Your total benefit is: 2043$
Your total yield is: 2%
Your total units by day: 1.25
...

**Historical data**

1/1/2016 - Example A - 1.5 units - 100$ benefit
2/1/2016 - Example B - 2.5 units - 200$ benefit
3/1/2016 - Example A - 3.5 units - 30$ benefit
4/1/2016 - Example C - 1.25 units - 500$ benefit
5/1/2016 - Example A - 1.5 units - 3$ benefit
6/1/2016 - Example A - 2.5 units - 5.4$ benefit

PREV PAGE - NEXT PAGE
```

What's the best way?

Answer (score 4):

**Don't be scared to use multiple queries.** I get the feeling you want to do this all in one go, don't. You might get it to work fot this situation, but it'll be difficult to maintain. Yes, you should try to keep your queries to a minimum, but don't overoptimise.

First you calculate your averages and your totals and return that instantly, This will give your first statistics. Then you have the first X items shown, I suggest you dont AJAX those either, but do that when you build that page. This is another query. After that, you are free to use your LIMIT freely in an AJAX call to show your next/prev.

By splitting the queries, you can optimize your AVG/SUM query to your needs, and optimize your plain lines query. This might even be an improvement to your current performance.

Comment: I absolutely agree. Aggregation (sums and averages) can and should be done in the database with an extra query. This also reduces the data that has to be sent from the database to your script. So ...  one aggregation query (averages, sums) as Martijn describes, then your limit query where you show the actual entries.